# ¿Se puede modificar el puntero de un input?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

¿Se puede modificar el puntero (cursor, línea parpadeante) del input, para darle otro estilo como más ancha, de otro color etc?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Agregarías por favor lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En  css puedes usar  `caret-color` para cambiar su color por ejemplo.

Pero no conozco alguna propiedad para hacerlo mas ancho, aunque hay posibilidades como [esta](http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html), [esta](https://codepen.io/verticalgrain/pen/MabMwz), [esta](http://jsbin.com/ehuki3/3/edit?html,js,output), o [esta](https://jsfiddle.net/3mz5z7vc/)

```css
input{
  caret-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```